# Add a seconds counter text to a sliced video with ffmpeg that starts from 0

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext, timecodes

I'm trying to convert a **small part** of a screen recording video into a GIF with ffmpeg. I would like to add a **seconds counter** on it as the frame rate of the GIF file is reduced, so I can guess the time passing from the counter.

Normally, assuming to start at 43 seconds and cutting after 33 seconds, the example video would have been encoded to GIF with:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "scale=300:-1,fps=5,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -ss 43 -t 33 out.gif
```

To print the timecode, I add the following after `fps=5,`:

```
drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':font='Arial':fontcolor=red:fontsize=14:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-6),
```

Doing so, prints a timecode on the output that starts from **00:00:43.000**, not from zero. Similarly the `timecode` option:

```
drawtext=text='':font='Arial':fontcolor=red:fontsize=14:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-6):timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':timecode_rate=5,
```

will ouput **00:00:43:0**. There doesn't seem to have a way to use the **"output" timecode** (that starts from 0); also, I would like to have the seconds only.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Formatting as seconds

Apparently a way to do it is using the frame number, like so:

```
drawtext=text='%{eif\:n/5-43\:d\:2}':font='Arial':fontcolor=red:fontsize=14:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-6),
```

that outputs **00**, **01**, etc. but the values have to be typed directly (hence not calculated by ffmpeg!). The `%{eif\:n/5-43\:d\:2}` part is composed like so:

- `n` is the current frame number
- `5` is the number of frames per seconds (was `fps=5` above)
- `43` is the number of seconds to subtract (from the start time `-ss 43`)
- `2` means a two-digit output, so *00* instead of *0*

### Formatting as *mm:ss*

To display minutes and seconds, or if the duration of the video is greater than 60 seconds and you want to display e.g. 83 seconds like **01:23**, use this syntax:

```
drawtext=text='%{eif\:(n/5-43)/60\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:mod((n/5-43)\,60)\:d\:2}':font='Arial':fontcolor=red:fontsize=14:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-6),
```

Explanation:

- `%{eif\:(n/5-43)/60\:d\:2}`

  - `n` is the current frame number
  - `5` is the number of frames per seconds (was `fps=5` above)
  - `43` is the number of seconds to subtract (from the start time `-ss 43`)
  - `/60` calculates the minutes from the seconds, e.g. 83 / 60 = 1
  - `2` format as a two-digit output, so *00* instead of *0*
- `\:`

  - Separator `:` (has to be escaped)
- `%{eif\:mod((n/5-43)\,60)\:d\:2}`

  - `mod` calculates the remainder (see below)
  - `n` is the current frame number
  - `5` is the number of frames per seconds (was `fps=5` above)
  - `43` is the number of seconds to subtract (from the start time `-ss 43`)
  - `\,60` calculates remainder (seconds) from the minutes, e.g. 83 mod 60 = 23
  - `2` format as a two-digit output, so *00* instead of *0*